Non-blocking copy from Host to Buffer with enqueue_copy
I am writing a code with PyOpenCL to offload heavy computations to GPU. To optimize the algorithm, I would like to parallel some of the memory transfer operations with further calculations. However, I am observing a blocking behaviour regardless:
import  numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl
from timeit import default_timer as dt

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)

a = np.random.random((1000, 1000, 500)).astype(np.float64)
mf = cl.mem_flags
start = dt()
a_buff = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_WRITE | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=a)
print(f'Buffer creation time: {dt()-start:0.4f} s')

start = dt()
event1 = cl.enqueue_copy(queue, a_buff, a, is_blocking=False)
event1.wait()
print(f'Copy time blocking 1: {dt()-start:0.4f} s')

start = dt()
event2 = cl.enqueue_copy(queue, a_buff, a, is_blocking=False)
event2.wait()
print(f'Copy time blocking 2: {dt()-start:0.4f} s')

start = dt()
event3 = cl.enqueue_copy(queue, a_buff, a, is_blocking=False)
print(f'Copy time non-blocking 1: {dt()-start:0.4f} s')

Console output:
Buffer creation time: 0.8559 s
Copy time blocking 1: 1.1018 s
Copy time blocking 2: 0.4177 s
Copy time non-blocking 1: 0.4364 s

The times of blocking and non-blocking copies are almost identical despite having is_blocking=False argument. I have read that if the NannyEvent obect returned by the copy is not kept until transfter finish, the operation would be blocking anyway. But that does did not help either.
Also, the first copy to the Buffer is substantially longer than the second.
My question is how can I achive non-blocking behaviour?

I don't know why it appears to be blocking, but opencl often copies a buffer into its own 4k aligned host memory before transferring it to the GPU, so that might be why the second is faster than the first. You can see when it does this, it uses about twice as much memory as you expected. Maybe it realised in the second call it doesn't have to make a third copy. I'm guessing though.
